# I2C communication pin and/or device getting damaged

Tags: raspberry-pi, i2c, damage

I have a Raspberry Pi communicating with some I2C client devices. Occasionally either the I2C client device fails or a Raspberry Pi pin (one of the I2C pins) is damaged. The only thing I can conceive as being a cause is the fact one of the I2C devices has its own 3.3v power supply. Both the I2C devices and the Raspberry Pi share a common ground, and the two signal lines are tied to 3.3v via 10k resistors. The ground is made common via a  cable that also carries the signal lines and power for the Raspberry Pi.

Here is (an updated) block diagram:

[image]

The 3.3v PS and I2C device (on left) are on a 2nd PCB separated by a 6" ribbon cable. The 24v power is supplied by this PCB to both boards. All the circuitry on the right of the cable (except for the Raspberry Pi) is on a single board plugged into the 40-pin Pi connector. This board provides the 5V/Gnd to the Raspberry Pi via the 40-pin connector. The ribbon cable carries logic-level slow-speed signals that operate solid-state, low voltage relays (basically LEDs) in addition to the 24v power/Gnd for the Pi, and the I2C lines.

The failures I have encountered include:

1. The I2C device on left being destroyed (requiring replacement in order for the I2C bus to work again). This has happened a few times.
2. One of the Raspberry Pi pins used for I2C becoming non-functional, i.e. permanently damaged. I do not know if it was used for SCL or SDA since in some versions, the pins used were changed.

I don't believe the RTC chip has ever failed, just the Raspi pin or more commonly, the I2C device with its own 3.3v PS.

The I2C being used on the Raspberry Pi is the software based gpio I2C overlay. Specifically (in /boot/config.txt): dtoverlay=i2c-rtc-gpio,ds3231,addr=0x68,i2c_gpio_sda=22,i2c_gpio_scl=23

Any ideas or suggestions? If the separate power supply for the I2C client devices is a problem, what would be a way to resolve it without sending a 3.3v power line from the Pi along the connecting cable?

Comment: Please include the pull-up resistors in the diagram. It makes it much easier to understand your question.

Comment: Also, how long are the cable, and what other signals or power supplies are carried on that cable? Does your system involve any high-current switched loads (motors, for examples)?

Comment: Scott - Hi, Can you please add more detail to the diagram? In addition to the comments above: (a) You say "I2C *devices*" (plural) but the diagram shows only one. (b) You explain (and the diagram shows) that one I2C device has its own 3.3 V power supply - but there is no 0 V / Gnd reference connection shown between the 3.3 V power supply and anything else. (c) What is the usage environment? (d) How many other I2C devices? How are *they* powered? (e) Which are the I2C devices being found to be damaged? How many? How often? (f) Any event which triggers damage to devices? (g) Can you add photos?

Comment: (1) Is your I2C channel temporarily or permanently damaged? (2) Rpi4B has 5 I2C channels, perhaps you can try another one. (3) You might find this SO Q&A helpful. 
Raspberry Pi 4 I2C bus not working correctly - SO, Asked 1 year, 4 months ago Active 1 year, 3 months ago Viewed 7k times
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62757687/raspberry-pi-4-i2c-bus-not-working-correctly/62786449#62786449.

Comment: I have improved the description and diagram to improve clarity per questions asked.

Comment: @Scott - Thanks for adding details. Unfortunately that showed there is much more detail needed (at least for me) to clarify the full configuration. For example, it's clear that there are more I2C devices than shown on the block diagram; you've now mentioned there are some SSRs, but none appear on the diagram (nor their load); and there are still outstanding question from earlier comments. IMHO it needs a full schematic, full context/history, photos (to help visualise the schematic) and yet more questions. So I'll have to let others takeover the troubleshooting from here, but sincere good luck!

Comment: There are no more I2C devices than what is shown. The relays are controlled by individual control lines. I didn't include them since they are not relevant, except to answer the question about high current loads and the type of cable. The load they represent is about 5mA to power their LEDs. Each is controlled by a single GPIO pin on the Raspi, and there has never been a problem with them.

Comment: The only possible cause I have been able to conceive is the use of a separated 3.3V power supply for the off-board I2C device. I suppose that if the ground connection over the cable were to be compromised it could cause the 3.3V along the I2C signal lines to be excessive. However, if that were the case, one would expect the Raspi to reboot due to the interruption of its own power.

One other possibility I can conceive is if there is some sort of surge over the ground connection, possibly due to introduced EMF or power usage fluctuations of the Pi itself.

Any thoughts? Ideas?