# Voltage issue on pull-up resistor

Tags: microcontroller, voltage, resistors, circuit-design, i2c

I have an I2C sensor circuit, 3.3V applied to SDA and SCL pin through 10k resistor.

I2C communication is not working so I have measured the voltage drop across the 10k resistors. It drops 2.86V and approximately to 10kohm values getting.

Is that resistor problem or is something else wrong?

I have used two sensors,  DPS310 and MPU9250 - SDA, SCL of both sensors pulled up with a 10K resistor.

Schematic:

```
MPIN 14-SDA
MPIN 15-SCL
```

[image]

Comment: How do you measure it? If there is communication on bus you won't measure 3.3V on bus or 0V over resistor.

Comment: Welcome to EE.SE! Please draw a schematic of what you have and how it's connected. Click on edit and the schematic symbol.

Comment: There are probably other pull-up resistors. We need the complete schematic.

Comment: Thanks you guys for fast reply, i have attached schematic,

Comment: (1) I assume Rpi4B on board I2C. Channel 0 has built in 1k8 pull up. Other channels have weaker pullups. (2) Most assembled I2C modules have on board 4k7/10k pullups.  (3) If you have too many I2C modules on same bus, the equivalent pull up impedance might exceed the usually allowable limit of 400pF. (4) I usually remove all the modules' on board 4l7/10k, so Rpi I2C on board 1k8 is the only one remaining. (5) If your bus speed is much higher that 100kHz, and the physical wiring is over 30cm, then things get unstable. (6) One workaround is do not overload the bus with too many devices.

Comment: My comment to this I2C question might explain more: (1) https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/596213/i2c-communication-pin-and-or-device-getting-damaged, (2) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62757687/raspberry-pi-4-i2c-bus-not-working-correctly, (3) https://penzu.com/public/2450c7ae.

Comment: ok ,I will check that , i have edited the thread  , i am using 2 sensor on same bus each pulled with 10K (3.3v), is that make issue..

Comment: (4) The following is problematic (a) It drops 2.86 V and approximately (b)10 ohm values. (5) 2.8V is a bit low. Rpi min Vout high is ~=2.8V. (6) 10 Ohm is also problematic. I remember I once used a DMM to measure the Rpi3B+ I2C pins pullups and found them around 1k7.

Comment: @tlfong01 iam really sorry , its 10k, i have checked all resister its values are correct

Comment: One more thing. If using Rpi, unstable I2C communication because of bad wiring/wrong wiring/ usually gives error message ***I/O Error #121***.

Comment: (5) Rpi I2C SCL/SDA built in pullups are 1k8, while other GPIO pins are much higher. I guess the designers know that 1k8 is optimum. So your 10k might be too weak for the I2C pins to pull down. Perhaps you can add 4k7 or even smaller in parallel to the 10k's, to try your luck. Sorry, supper time, see you later.

Comment: Are you sure those signals are not changing while you are measuring their voltage? Is it possible that your DMM is showing you some *average* value of a fluctuating voltage?

Comment: (6) I see that you are using DPS310 and MPU9250. I once played with MPU9250 and found a I2C problem, that I needed to do something called "block read" which I latter found that my Rpi I2C module does not support that, and a workaround is to use something called "bus stretching" but that required lowering bus speed from 400/100kHz down to 50kHz. Unluckily Rpi3B+, because of a Rpi cpu problem design bug, cannot lower bus speed. Then I read that the experts suggested to use another device (Bosch) to replace MPU9250. So my lesson learnt is that MPU9250 (or MPU6250) has problem talking to Rpi I2C.

Comment: (7) So my troubleshooting suggestion is to put away MPU9250, and test DPS310 alone. This is the trick of Occam Razor: "make it as simple as possible, but not simpler". (8) Now let me come back to (9) DPS310 Digital Barometric Pressure Sensor - Infineon
https://www.infineon.com/dgdl/Infineon-DPS310-DataSheet-v01_02-EN.pdf?fileId=5546d462576f34750157750826c42242. 

You remind me the following: (10) Rpi3 BMP180 Barometer Sensor Interface Problem, 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60274562/rpi3-bmp180-barometer-sensor-interface-problem/60292757#60292757.  /to continue, ...

Comment: (11)  You see that, in the BMP180 case, the problem is quite complicated. Your DPS310 prolbm might be as complicated. (12) For Rpi, the troubleshooting tricks are: (a) Use utilities such as "i2cdetect" to detect the I2C device, (b) write a simple python program to "ping" the device, by reading and/or read/after/write a R/W register (usually the config reg). Just to make sure at least you can read or red/after/write a device register.  (13) If you just follow a tutorial and simply copy the complete long code and hope everything goes well, you might likely experience the same BMP180 problem.

Comment: (14) DPS130 can talk I2C and also SPI. If you give up I2C finally, you can try talking SPI. My experience is that SPI is twice less difficult that I2C.  (15) Or try BMP280 for which you can find more references and tutorials. Anyway, good luck and happy learning. Cheers.

Comment: (15) You might like to let us know which module you are using, and if you are following any tutorial. (16) Barometric pressure shield v1.0.0, for lolin (wemos) d1 mini hp303b i2c, compatible dps310 digital pressure sensor module - AliExpress US$1.50
https://pt.aliexpress.com/item/32947207904.html?spm=a2g0o.search0301.0.0.36215b71jlKwS5&algo_pvid=c9a98858-42e5-40b3-a6db-4fe33abd965d&algo_exp_id=c9a98858-42e5-40b3-a6db-4fe33abd965d-0

Comment: You are leaving out important info. Are all chips, or at least their IO supply, also powered with 3.3V supply, or some other voltage?

Comment: (16) 
There seems to be some confusion about pullup resistors. I would recommend newbies this free on line tutorial:
Pull-up Resistors (Calculating Pull-up Resistor Value) - Electronics Tutorials
https://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/logic/pull-up-resistor.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The datasheet for DPS310 suggests a supply voltage (VDDIO) of 1.8V with a 10Kohm pull-up.  If you're using a greater VDDIO, perhaps you need to increase the value of the pull-up resister proportionally so that when SDI is in use it can drive the line low as well as high.

Comment: That doesn't mske much sense: (a) VDDIO is well within the specified range. (b) greater pullups would make things even worse (OP has 10k already). (c) in open drain logic pull-up resistors drive the lines high, pins drive the lines low.

Comment: My initial thinking is that SDI is not getting low when a logic zero is to be sent because of the greater VDDIO.  A greater valued pullup resistor will cause a greater voltage drop between VDDIO and SDI, thus allowing SDI to go low when it needs to.

Comment: A lpgic lpw pulls SDI tp ground, it doesn't matter what VDDIO is. And the voltage drop accross the resistor is independent of its value.

Comment: For your understanding: a **strong** pullup is a **low-value** pullup.